# how to plot data that occurs 3 monthly on a daily chart in excel through time

Tags: charts

I am drawing 2 charts one of share price and one of value. The share price can be obtained daily, but the value (which I calculated) can only be calculated from 3 monthly data.

I need to plot both charts daily which therefore means that I have to hold the value data static for 3 months up until I can use new data for the calculation. As you can see in the image the share price chart has a nice trend, but the valuation chart has straight lines (due to the data having to be static for many days).

Is there a way for me to get the valuation chart to look like the share price chart?

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to plot your 90 day "value" data daily?  If it absolutely has to be (e.g. management requirement), then your chart will look as its presented.  And, FWIW, there's nothing wrong with it-it accurately reflects what you're calculating.  Otherwise, you could just plot when the value data is calculated (i.e. every 90th day).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the linear interpolation method to make your graph more "close to reality". [Linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)

Unfortunately - it can't predict the future. Which means - only between two known function values you will get something more "realistic".